# WCF: There was no endpoint listening

Tags: c#, wcf

I try to build an application to send messages between 2 machines usinf `WCF` and found this article:
http://tnvbalaji.com/articles/wcf-tutorials/

After follow all the steps and when the server and the client runs on the same machine all works fine.
when i try to connect to the server from other machine in the same network i received the error  There was no endpoint listening.

```
baseAddress = "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfMathServLib/MathService/"
```

so after i run the client from another machine i have changed this to my machine ipaddress instead of localhost in both app.config and still received this error.
BTW the Firewall is disable in the server machine.
What is my problem ?

Comment: what about firewalls?

Comment: You're not running the listener in the Visual Studio development web server, right? That web server doesn't allow non-local connections. You should find a way to test whether there is actual connectivity between the two machines on the port in question.

Comment: Firewall is disabled, and the server runs from visual studio, is it a problem ?

Comment: @user1860934, please read *all* the words in my comment.

Comment: You can't simply change it to IP addresses and have it work in a deployment situation like it does dynamically at runtime on a local machine. When you start the service, can you actually visit the address specified locally on that machine? That's the best place to start.  As @DanielA.White mentioned, there are firewall issues to deal with beyond that, as well as possible authentication requirements.

Comment: Are you running instances of Visual Studio on these servers to test this? It sounds like from your comment that you are.  That's really not something I would advise, even if you configure your VS web server to allow remote connections.

Comment: I am sorry but i am new developer and didn't understand what i need to do, can you elaborate ?

Comment: @user1860934, just click the first linked question under "Related" on the right.

Comment: I didn't understand how to solve it

Comment: @user1860934, move to IIS. And read the comments on this question - there are suggestions you haven't tried.

Comment: You said, "i have changed this to my machine ipaddress instead of localhost in both app.config". You need to replace the localhost with your IP address in only one app.config file which belong to the client application. You should not change anything in service's app.config file.

Answer (score 0):

try publish the WCF service and deploy in IIS.
just like hosting a website, you require to host the WCF service to enable access by other machine.

after the hosting, browse the service and use the ip address as you service reference.